How do I read a Property Store Binary File [MS-PROPSTORE] back into an IPropertyStore?
I'm trying to read a Property Store Binary File from a VT_BLOB. The code gives no errors but in the end propertyStore.GetCount(count) gives me 0, while I can clearly see at least two properties in the file when I open it with Notepad.
I'm using the following code:
Dim ptr As IntPtr, propertyStore As IPropertyStore, persistStream As IPersistStream
Functions.PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore(GetType(IPropertyStore).GUID, ptr)
propertyStore = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ptr, GetType(IPropertyStore))
persistStream = propertyStore
Dim ptr2 As IntPtr = Functions.SHCreateMemStream(propVariant.union.bstrblobVal.pData, propVariant.union.bstrblobVal.cbSize)
Dim stream As IStream = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ptr2, GetType(IStream))
stream.Seek(0, 0, Nothing)
Dim b(0) As Byte, r As UInteger
For y As UInt32 = 0 To propVariant.union.bstrblobVal.cbSize - 1
    stream.Read(b, 1, r)
    'Debug.WriteLine(b(0) & ",,," & r)
Next
stream.Seek(0, 0, Nothing)
Dim st As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG
stream.Stat(st, 0)
Dim l As Integer = persistStream.Load(stream)
Dim pc As UInt32
propertyStore.GetCount(pc)
Debug.WriteLine(pc)

Edit: I've tried and it seems like I can feed whatever value into persistStream.Load, it's never errors. Seems like it just doesn't react at all.

I found the solution. By default the IPropertyStore from PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore is read-only. So you need to call SetFlags(0) on IPersistSerializedPropStorage, so this is how your construct an IPropertyStore from a Property Store Binary File:
Dim ptr As IntPtr, propertyStore As IPropertyStore, persistSerializedPropStorage As IPersistSerializedPropStorage
Functions.PSCreateMemoryPropertyStore(GetType(IPropertyStore).GUID, ptr)
propertyStore = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ptr, GetType(IPropertyStore))
persistSerializedPropStorage = propertyStore
persistSerializedPropStorage.SetFlags(0)
persistSerializedPropStorage.SetPropertyStorage(result.union.bstrblobVal.pData, result.union.bstrblobVal.cbSize)
propertyStore.GetValue(_propertyKey, result)

